# Is there a community specifically for big-data analysis, Hadoop, Spark, Kafka, etc.?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a community specifically for big-data analysis, Hadoop, Spark, Kafka, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

I am no expert on the topic, but [Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) has tags for all the things you were naming.

Comment: Also, a [big-data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-data) tag on [Open Data.SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Data Science is too general for what i am talking about. My objective is to have a community for real time data analysis for decision making using tools like hadoop , spark , kafka and other such tools in this ecosystem.

Comment: @IjazKhan: I do not know how the data-science and big-data communities are structured, but as long as there is sufficient overlap between them, I do not see a problem and splitting them would even be harmful. For example, we do not have separate communities for different subfields of [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/), different [programming languages](http://stackoverflow.com/), or different flavours or flavours of [English](http://english.stackexchange.com/) either.

Answer (score 3):

[There was one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40518/big-data) but it didn't get enough uptake so it closed down.

Comment: "No beta users with 200 reputation yet" - wow, that's sad.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well it didn't even last 2 weeks. Does the 200 rep include association bonus, or does it need 200 unique reputation on the site? (Not that it really matters here, I guess. It doesn't look like it was heading anywhere due to the other poor stats).

Comment: Good question, I assume it does include the bonus, which makes it even more sad...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it does, as it counted me when I had 200 something rep, counting AssoBon.

Comment: Closed betas might not have any users, and thus no users with rep over 200.  (I don't know; I haven't seen other closed proposals to compare.)  Anyway, three years is a long time in tech, so that closure doesn't necessarily mean a new proposal would fail.  One way to find out... (and I see someone's done so).

Answer (score 3):

I opened a proposal , those who are intersted can vote here.

[Big Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102454/big-data?referrer=ajpCoKtv6aOWqQSP7qmkfw2)